# How to Deploy to Intellij IDEA Tomcat Folder?

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, intellij-idea

I use Intellij IDEA 11.1.2 Ultimate Edition. I run Tomcat 6 from Intellij IDEA. Beside my .war application I have another folder that has static HTML files. When I run tomcat manually from command line I put that folder under Tomcat's webapp folder and it automatically deploys it and works. However I want to debug my application so I want to run Tomcat from Intellij IDEA. I think that Intellij IDEA deploys tomcat applications into .IntelliJIdea11\system\tomcat folder. Where I can put my folder that contains static files when I run Tomcat from Intellij IDEA?

(I request the main page of static HTML file folder within an iframe at one of my HTML pages of .war file )

Any ideas?

Comment: You should have your static files in war also. You can do it in Web Facet settings in section Web resource directories.

Comment: @chalimartines con you explain it more?

Answer (score 12):

Tomcat Run configuration has an option to deploy other applications from the server (that already present in the original webapps folder), like your static files:

[image: deploy]

Another option would be to create a second module for the static content with another artifact and deploy both artifacts from IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Tip: check deployment tab for those who build WAR Artifacts via mvn

Answer (score 1):

I think that CrazyCoder's answer is a little bit better. But here is my solution.

- Go to `File -> Project Structure...`
- Select your Web facet
- In section Web resource directories click to `+`
- `Web resource directory path` is your static content
- `Relative path in deployment directory` is where you want to find it in your application war

[image: Project structure]

Comment: Thanks a million, I forgot to create the web facet and I struggled with it for a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug you have no need to run Tomcat from IDEA. You can use remote debugging feature.
Just set up Tomcat to accept debug(listen to particular port). And create debug configuration from IDEA to attach to this port.